# While parsing a file into an array, only the last element is initalised

Tags: java, arrays, file, parsing, element

I'm trying to get an array of words out of a file (that I wrote myself). The first line of the file tells me how long the array should be, but for some reason, only the last element is initialized. I am a beginner so I'm sure it's a simple fix but I just can't seem to figure it out...

```
public class WordReader {

     String[] words;

     public WordReader() {
         String line;
         String[] tokens = new String[2];
         int counter = 0;
         try{
             File infile = new File("resources/FunnyWords.txt");

             Scanner reader = new Scanner(infile);
             while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                 line = reader.nextLine();
                 if (line.contains("Number of words")){
                    tokens = line.split(",");
                    continue;
                 }
                 int length = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                 words = new String[length];
                 words[counter] = line;
                 counter++;
             }

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help.. 
Thanks!

Comment: And the contents of the file looks like ...?

Comment: continue means "go next line", are you sure you need that ?

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, you recreate the `words` array ... probably should be done in the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

The below two lines which initialize the array should be done only once and not for each line/word in the file.

```
int length = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
words = new String[length];
```

Change it as

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
    line = reader.nextLine();
     if (line.contains("Number of words")){
        tokens = line.split(",");
        int length = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        words = new String[length]; //Initialize the words array
        continue;
     }
      words[counter] = line;
      counter++;
     //Or a one liner -  words[counter++] = line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

within your `while` loop you have

```
words = new String[length];
```

which creates a new `String` array *in each and every* loop iteration.

So you actually assign each line to an array of its own and only keep the last one.